# Generic Types: There is no implicit reference conversion from ToolStripStatusLabel to Control

Tags: c#, delegates, invoke, multithreading, toolstripstatuslabel

I'm wanting to update the UI from a SerialPort DataReceived event handler. I discovered a problem because the event handler was implicitly running in a different thread to the form, so rather than simply update the UI...

```
myLabel.Text = "Some text";
```

...I had to take the following approach:

```
    InvokeControlAction<Label>(myLabel, lbl=> lbl.Text= "Some text");
...
    public static void InvokeControlAction<t>(t cont, Action<t> action) where t : Control
    {
        if (cont.InvokeRequired)
        {
            cont.Invoke(new Action<t, Action<t>>(InvokeControlAction),
                          new object[] { cont, action });
        }
        else
        { 
            action(cont); 
        }
    }
```

So far so good... However, now I want to update a ToolStripStatusLabel - using the same approach yields a 'there is no implicit reference conversion between ToolStripStatusLabel and Forms.Control' error.

From what I have read, the problems stems from the fact that you can't Invoke a ToolStripStatusLabel.

So how best do I handle this?

Note: delegates, etc are at the threshold of my current ability, so an explanation alongside a solution would  be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:** Just to clarify, I tried to create ToolStripStatusLabel equivalent of InvokeControlAction, but this won't work because it doesn't have an invoke method.

**RESULT**: After revisiting my solution, I've implemented it as an Extension Method as Jimmy originally suggested.

I created an static *ExtensionMethod* class (in it's own 'ExtensionMethods' namespace), added in the InvokeOnToolStripItem method, add a 'using ExtensionMethods;' directive in my original class and called the methods as follows:

```
tsStatusValue.InvokeOnToolStripItem(ts => ts.Text = "ALARM signal received");
```

Comment: @Stecya - Care to elaborate? I think the solution *might* involve the StatusStrip's (that the ToolStripStatusLabel is an child of) .invoke method, but I wouldn't know how to begin to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToolStripStatusLabel` does not inherit from `Control`, and that's why your generic constraint fails for the exact reason you posted.

What is more, `ToolStripStatusLabel` (or any `ToolStripItem` in fact) doesn't have `Invoke` method. Luckily, containing `ToolStrip` has, which can be easily accessed using `GetCurrentParent` method.

Here's extension method that works on any `ToolStripItem`:

```
public static void InvokeOnToolStripItem<T>(this T item, Action<T> action)
    where T : ToolStripItem
{
    ToolStrip parent = item.GetCurrentParent();
    if (parent.InvokeRequired)
    {
        parent.Invoke((Delegate)action, new object[] { item });
    }
    else
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

You can use it by simply calling:

```
myToolStripLabel.InvokeOnToolStripItem(label => label.Text = "Updated!");
myToolStripProgressBar.InvokeOnToolStripItem(bar => bar.PerformStep());
```

Comment: Jimmy, you are following the route I have travelled! I had already tried the first solution in that CodeProject article and it didn't work.... doesn't recognise SetText and base.Items

Comment: You seem to be extending the Toolstrip controls; I embedded the code in my form but it works just the same. Not sure if there is any disadvantage here, but certainly it works!

Comment: Yep, extension method works for the very base class of ToolStripItem. This covers ToolStripLabel (which is base class for ToolStripStatusLabel) and few more items you can put in ToolStrip/StatusStrip controls.

Comment: Creating an extended control, though, means I can't use the form designed-time tools... which is a pain.

Comment: There is no extended control in play here - it's [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) (look at the `this` keyword before first argument). You still use regular ToolStripStatusLabel controls, and simply introduce new static class which contains this extension method.

Comment: Done some homework on Extension Methods and now implemented as you suggested - thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the error message, you have writen

```
where t : Control
```

but ToolStripStatusLabel does not inherit from Control.

Not sure if that helps you at all and don't really have a solution yet :(

Comment: Yeah, I'd tried creating a ToolStripStatusLabel alternative, but the problem is that it doesn't have an invoke method.